# Mysql Multiple Arguments for "Where" Clause

Tags: mysql

I just want to ask if it is possible to have multiple arguments for, `where` clause in mysql?

Something like:

```
SELECT * from tblId where id=1,2,3,4
```

Supposed I only want to select id's `1`,`2`,`3`,`4`. I tried this but give me error. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 7):

```
SELECT * FROM tblId WHERE id IN (1, 2, 3, 4);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this query:

```
SELECT * from tblId where id in (1,2,3,4)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `in`:

```
SELECT * from tblId where id in (1,2,3,4)
```

Answer (score -4):

Try this
    SELECT * from tblId where id =1 and id =2 and id =3 and id =4

Comment: `id` could never equal `1`, `2`, `3`, and `4` at the same time.

Comment: You should do it with an `OR` instead of the `AND`, I guess... Anyway, this is not the optimal way.

Comment: sorry for the mistake, it should be OR. but this is the simplest if u need immediate fix or dont know the syntax of a new database for '.... in (1,2,3,4)'